# URL parameters but ?mark is missing

Tags: http, web, url

I am new(trainee) to the web development and I just started studying its "language". I have to report every day to my boss but I have to use the correct terms. I have been reading about [URL anatomy](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url), in order to explain the fragments of this URL: ***https://www.c2ccertified.org/api_v2/search&username=rikotech&offset=50***.

I see something that looks like query parameters to me: `offset` and `username`, but I don't see the question mark.

I don't know how to fragment(in correct terms) this part of the URL:

> search&username=rikotech&offset=50

Are these query parameters? Because it seems to me that they serve that purpose - semantically. They filter the result from the API server.

**------EDIT------**

I found useful tool to use Node.js URL parser:

```
url = new URL(`https://www.c2ccertified.org/api_v2/search&username=rikotech&offset=50`)
console.log(url);
```

It did the job for me:

```
URL {
  href:
   'https://www.c2ccertified.org/api_v2/search&username=rikotech&offset=50',
  origin: 'https://www.c2ccertified.org',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.c2ccertified.org',
  hostname: 'www.c2ccertified.org',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/api_v2/search&username=rikotech&offset=50',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no "?", then there's no query, thus no query arguments. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#components.